Are people with sinful addictions doomed?
According to Acts 3:19-21:

19 Repent therefore, and turn back, that your sins may be blotted out,
20 that times of refreshing may come from the presence of the Lord, and that he may send the Christ appointed for you, Jesus,
21 whom heaven must receive until the time for restoring all the things about which God spoke by the mouth of his holy prophets long ago.

I see repentance as requirement for Gods forgiveness, meaning the complete stop to any sin or sinful behaviors.
Now this is easier said then done for addictions.
Addictions have this characteristics:

Compulsiveness: An overwhelming urge to engage in the behavior or use the substance, often uncontrollable.
Tolerance: Increasing amounts of the substance or intensity of the behavior are required to achieve the same effect.
Withdrawal: Physical and psychological symptoms that occur when the addictive behavior or substance use is reduced or stopped.
Negative Impact: Continued engagement despite knowing it causes significant problems in personal, social, occupational, or health areas.
Loss of Control: Difficulty in limiting or stopping the addictive behavior or substance use.
Preoccupation: Persistent thoughts and focus on the substance or behavior, often at the expense of other activities and responsibilities.

In Summary: Stopping an addiction is not easy and extremely difficult. So while it is easy to regret addictions and make genuine efforts to stop one, there isn't a method with guaranteed success. Addictive behaviors are often done consciously, meaning the case for active sin can be made.
Assuming an addictions that is inherently sinful e.g. a sex-addiction(outside of marriage) or an addiction impeding with obedience like Gaming-addiction(no time to do what God says) or a self-destructive addiction like fentanyl:

Is the Assumption that repentance is required for forgiveness correct?
Is an addiction "forgivable"? Note that due to the nature of repeatableness, it means that shortly after the process of repenting and receiving forgiveness, a person sins again (Relapse). This potentially could undermine the effect Gods forgiveness could have.
Is mastering the addiction a requirement for salvation? (Lets exclude the edge-case of repenting and dying before the next chance to indulge in the addictive behavior arises)
Are there differences between denominations on this topic of forgiveness of addictions? What is their reasoning for one denomination being more or less strict on addictions?


I don't have time to attempt an Answer now, but... "Are there differences between denominations?" Hoo boy, are there!

Is your interest merely academic and theoretical ? The above is a very personal matter between the soul and God. Jesus Christ actually healed people who came to him for help. It was not theoretical with them - they were desperate. But the above inquiry seems almost clinical. Is that how you wish to be answered ? Clinically ?

@NigelJ My approach to answer a personal question is to abstract it into a form so that it can be answered generally. Since I know how how to ask it in an academic way I can help myself and others with a similar question while relying on the high expertise of the people here. So to answer your question: Yes I want it answered clinically.

Welcome to Christianity! Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Look to  the Lord for help in overcoming addiction. Don't try to do it on your own. Pray and ask the Lord. Hope this helps.

Luke wrote two consecutive verses that cover the first three points:

Is the Assumption that repentance is required for forgiveness correct?:


Luke 17:3: Take heed to yourselves: If thy brother trespass against thee, rebuke him; and if he repent, forgive him.

Yes, repentance is required.
Repentance means to change one's behaviour and attitude.
It doesn't make sense to forgive someone for something if they intend to continue doing it.

… shortly after the process of repenting and receiving forgiveness, a person sins again (Relapse)
Is mastering the addiction a requirement?


Luke 17:4: And if he trespass against thee seven times in a day, and seven times in a day turn again to thee, saying, I repent; thou shalt forgive him.

Mastering it is definitely the goal, and for all character development, not only for addiction.
Perfection would be ideal, but is not always attained. It is the process of improvement in character that is important.
If one makes only token efforts and doesn't noticeably improve after each relapse, it isn't real repentance.
Real repentance requires real change.

Are there differences between denominations on this topic?

There are differences between denominations on all topics; there's nothing special about addiction.

Every person who has received the Lord Jesus, who has been born from above by grace through faith, has done so by repenting of their sin as they understand it (understanding will grow) and believing on the Lord Jesus Christ as they perceive Him (understanding will grow).
Every such person continues to struggle against sin and fails in that struggle to varying degrees for their entire earthly life.  Were it not so there would be no proffered avenue for continued confession to God and forgiveness and cleansing by the blood of the Lord Jesus as we mature:

But if we walk in the light, as he is in the light, we have fellowship one with another, and the blood of Jesus Christ his Son cleanseth us from all sin. If we say that we have no sin, we deceive ourselves, and the truth is not in us. If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just to forgive us our sins, and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness. If we say that we have not sinned, we make him a liar, and his word is not in us. - 1 John 7:1-10

We are all addicts of sin. Whichever particular sins the Spirit of God in us lusts against it is just there that our flesh lusts back in return, necessitating Paul's exposition of Romans chapter 7.  Those addicted to particular substances must not be made to feel as though they are in a different category.  Some of our sins are more obvious and immediate than others but we are all sinners and we all need Jesus.
Everyone of us needs to grow in the grace and knowledge of the Lord Jesus Christ.  There is no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus.  The sinner who believes and yet still falls needs to be reminded of this hope:  In Christ we are held innocent and have the wherewithal to learn to become innocent.  Christ in us, the hope of glory.
Take heart all who are weary, broken, chained, and in despair because of addiction.  Your sin is no greater than the Apostle Paul's and your hope is no different either:

O wretched man that I am! who shall deliver me from the body of this death? I thank God through Jesus Christ our Lord. So then with the mind I myself serve the law of God; but with the flesh the law of sin.  There is therefore now no condemnation to them which are in Christ Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit. 
For the law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus hath made me free from the law of sin and death. - Romans 7:24-8:2

